# C++ What does this line of code mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, using, member

I've seen this in a project called [Selene](https://github.com/jeremyong/Selene) (a C++11 Lua wrapper) and I was wandering what it does?

```
using Fun = std::function<void()>;
using PFun = std::function<void(Fun)>;
```

It is a private member of a class (Selector).

Surrounding code:

```
namespace sel {
class State;
class Selector {
private:
    friend class State;
    State &_state;
    using Fun = std::function<void()>;
    using PFun = std::function<void(Fun)>;

    // Traverses the structure up to this element
    Fun _traverse;
    // Pushes this element to the stack
    Fun _get;
    // Sets this element from a function that pushes a value to the
    // stack.
    PFun _put;

    // Functor is stored when the () operator is invoked. The argument
    // is used to indicate how many return values are expected
    using Functor = std::function<void(int)>;
    mutable std::unique_ptr<Functor> _functor;

    Selector(State &s, Fun traverse, Fun get, PFun put)
        : _state(s), _traverse(traverse),
          _get(get), _put(put), _functor{nullptr} {}

    Selector(State &s, const char *name);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a C++11 syntax which covers `typedef` functionality ([and more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alias_templates)).
In this case, it makes an alias called `Fun`, which is the same type as an `std::function<void()>`:

```
using Fun = std::function<void()>; // same as typedef std::function<void()> Fun
```

This means you can do this:

```
void foo() 
{
  std::cout << "foo\n";
}

Fun f = foo; // instead of std::function<void()> f = foo;
f();
```

Similarly for `PFun`.

Comment: hmm, I didn't knew you could use "using" inside classes similarly to typedef's do. I thought the "using" keyword was only for namespaces. thank you for the answer.

Comment: @SanduLiviuCatalin It is C++11 stuff, also used for alias templates. I added a note and a link on that.

Comment: @SanduLiviuCatalin it makes type definitions read the same left-to-right as variable definitions, so it is a good habit to start using  (pun intended) yourself.